# How to check if given series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given this series:

$$\sum_{m=5}^\infty\left(\frac 7{5m^{5.8}} \right)$$

I can write is as:

$$\frac 75 \sum_{m=5}^\infty\left(\frac 1{m^{5.8}} \right)$$

Now, it seems $\frac {1}{m^{5.8}}$ is a Harmonic series hence it should diverge. How to proceed from here?

$$$$
**Edit**

The above series is a $P$ series i.e. series of the form:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^p} $$

which means the series **converges** if $\text{p > 1}$ and **diverges** if $\text{p < 1}$.

Comment: It is not harmonic.  The harmonic series is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1k$, which diverges.  Now, for any number $\alpha>1$, the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{k^\alpha}$ converges.  For the series of interest, $\alpha =5.8>1$.  Therefore, the series of interest converges.

Comment: @Dr.MV edit and corrected.

Comment: And now, you've answered your own question.

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks for correcting me.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!  - Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sequences is not convergent. From Basel's Problem,  notice that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{5.8}} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

For the proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2).

This implies that $$\sum_{k=5}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{5.8}} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{5.8}} \le \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Therefore, your series is convergent, and converges to a value smaller than $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: You have applied the comparison test right?

Comment: @vivek Yes, I think so.. I don't know what it is called.